# Bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Tags: c++, c

I am trying buffer overflow and I encountered this error. Is there any way to stop bash from ignoring null bytes? (Was injecting shellcode).
Google search did not help me much.

Code

`

```
  if(argc==1) {
      printf("Usage: %s input\n",argv[0]);
      exit(0);
  }

  strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n",buf);
  return 0;
```

`

Comment: Why are you providing C code as an example for a question tagged as bash?

Comment: ...if your complaint still involves bash (as given in the title), explain *how*. It's clearly not a c/c++ question alone, either, so I'm not sure the new tagging helps. I'm assuming you're trying to read the output of your C program into bash? Your question should include everything needed (albeit with the least code possible) for someone else to see your problem themselves.

Comment: Was trying to inject .bin/bash in my c code through buffer overflow to get shellcode execution.

Comment: I managed to get everything right , overwriting the return address and NOP sled but when I gave my string as input to my program all my nop instructions were ignored

Comment: Why tagged for twop different languages? This looks like C.

Comment: Because this same code could be written in c++, And I used c++ (just not using cout and cin in the code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash variables are stored as C strings. C strings are NUL-terminated. They thus cannot store NULs *by definition*.

Consider storing each NUL-delimited component as a separate element of an array. For example:

```
pieces=( a '' bc d ); tail='efg'
printf '%s\0' "${pieces[@]}"; printf '%s' "$tail"
```

...will emit `a\0\0bc\0d\0efg`, with a literal NUL in place of each `\0`.

Comment: Looks like I'm missing something, but `echo -e "a\0b"` outputs `ab`. When piping to hexdump, you'll also see the null byte between `a` and `b`

Comment: @hek2mgl, any shell implementing `echo -e` is flouting the POSIX definition of `echo`, and I refuse to acknowledge its existence.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...the standards-compliant way to expand a format string with `\0` escapes for NULs would be `printf '%b' 'a\0b'`.

Comment: Ok, got that. How is it possible that `echo -e` can deal with null bytes having that any internal string representation is a C string?

Comment: @hek2mgl, there's no NUL byte in that input -- it's a backslash followed by a `0`. Can always `putc()` or similar.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...if you were running `echo -e $'a\0b'`, *that* would be a literal NUL byte in the argument, and it would disappear in the process.

Comment: I see. Thank you!